# Python to file - Best way to store strings with 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am looping through files and applying transformations to them. These transformations are stored as a 4x4 numpy array.
It has the following shape.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This 2D array needs to be saved with two file names. The working file and the reference file that the transformation applies to.

Since I'm trying to multiprocess this work, I need to save this data to disk. This information will be read back in, later, to predict future transformations. I'm interested in using pandas, possibly with multi-indexing? I can't seem to figure out how to store this information though.

So to be clear, I'll have info like

```
file1, file2, [[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0]]

file2, file3, [[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0]]

file4, file5, [[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0]]

file10, file13, [[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I appreciate any direction that can be given!

Comment: use json? or will that not work

Comment: pandas has a good overview page on ways you can store/read dataframes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: The nearest I can seem to come up with:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], [1,1,1,1]], columns=['data1','data2','data3','data4'])

But this carries the '1' through all fields

Comment: I considered JSON, but will there be a negative performance  impact by converting the numpy array to a list?

Comment: pickle it? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html , you can use pickle/cPickle for saving and loading objects.

Comment: @Maria `df.to_pickle` might work as well?

Comment: @jmunsch yeah, why not? I'm not not sure Rukie needs a dataframe. You can pickle any object of your liking ^_^.

Comment: Is [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) not enough?